# What are the different types of errors in python?

Tags: python

What are the basic error types in programming?

Is it,
Syntax/logic/semantic
Or
Syntax/logic/runtime
(My tutor says runtime errors are not a main type of programming error)

Are logic errors and semantic errors are the same type.
Is zerodivisionerror is also a type of runtime error

Comment: This shows the [hierarchy of the built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) (or [for py3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy))

Comment: In general you can always subclass `Exception` though, so it's impossible to list all possible exceptions.

Comment: In addition to this, it can be any subclass of `BaseException`. In Python <=2.5 you could raise a string too...

Answer (score 3):

These errors can, and should, be defined by modules and projects as they are developed - so, there is no limited and "closed" set of errors like you are asking for.

Python introspection capabilities allow one to see, through the interactive console, which errors are defined as derived directly from "Exception" - but there could be more:

```
>>> [err.__name__ for err in  Exception.__subclasses__()]
['TypeError', 'StopIteration', 'ImportError', 'OSError', 'EOFError', 'RuntimeError', 'NameError', 'AttributeError', 'SyntaxError', 'LookupError', 'ValueError', 'AssertionError', 'ArithmeticError', 'SystemError', 'ReferenceError', 'BufferError', 'MemoryError', 'Warning', 'error', 'Error']
```

Note that exception itself is derived from BaseException, which subclasses are not limited to "error" exceptions, but to Exceptions used in flow control as well:

```
>>> [err.__name__ for err in  BaseException.__subclasses__()]
['Exception', 'GeneratorExit', 'SystemExit', 'KeyboardInterrupt']
```

Bottom line: knowing the total number of errors is impossible and irrelevant for learning the language. Each function/library you are dealing with can define new ones, and you should check the documentation to know which exceptions they can throw.

(On a side note, the `__sublass__` method I used above does return a list of the classes that are direct descendants of that class. I them pick the `__name__` attribute of each class to display)

The document posted by @GP89 in the comments will also show the errors which are not direct descendants of exception:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy